# Getting Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am executing a load test in jmeter. My request is to run 4 API in parallel so i am using parallel controller in jmeter, but during execution i am intermittenly getting below two response from jmeter in each run

1. "Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException"
2. "Response code:Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLException
   Response message:Non HTTP response message: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"
   Please any suggestion will be welcome.
   I have increased the Tcpip port to 65536.

Comment: Can you please uncheck the "Keep Alive" flag in the HTTP Request and run the test again ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the root cause of the issue, in order to do this you need to:

1. [Enable debugging of SSL connections in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html), add the next line to *system.properties* file:

   ```
   javax.net.debug=all
   ```
2. [Enable debug logging for JMeter SSL components](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/), add the next lines to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.util.HttpSSLProtocolSocketFactory" level="debug" />
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager" level="debug" />
   <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
   ```

This way you will get way more information in [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) and [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) which could be analyzed.